# converting types returned from fetchall()

Tags: python, psycopg2

I'm using psycopg2, and I run the following code:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database = mydb_name, host = mydb_server, user = mydb_uname, password = mydb_pwd)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT desiredParams FROM tableOfInterest;")
all_data = cur.fetchall()
nlargest = heapq.nlargest(5, all_data)
```

This returns a list of tuples with decimals:

> [(Decimal('254.000'),), (Decimal('154.000'),), (Decimal('244.000'),),
>   (Decimal('134.000'),), (Decimal('254.000'),)]

How can I convert this into something more like:

> [254.000, 154.000, 244.000, 134.000, 254.000]

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decimals are a fix point number that match nicely with database number types.  They are really useful as is, but if I cant convince you to use them.

```
largest = [float(d[0]) for d in nlargest]
```

would give

```
[254.0, 154.0, 244.0, 134.0, 254.0]
```

or even better since cur is a iterible

```
cur.execute("SELECT desiredParams FROM tableOfInterest;")
nlargest = [float(g[0]) for g in heapq.nlargest(5, cur)]
```

In an attempt to make it pretty

```
cur.execute("SELECT param FROM tableOfInterest ORDER BY param DESC FIRST 5;")
nlargest = [float(r.param) for r in cur]
```

or skip the list building and just do it

```
cur.execute("SELECT param FROM tableOfInterest ORDER BY param DESC FIRST 5;")
for param, in cur:
    stuff_to_do_with_first_5(float(param))
```

the way to bind that looks good but is really bad (due to pyscopg's mishandling of bind variables).  The problem with this is that pysco just % the values into the string and thus hides the ability to inject sql into your string.

```
cur.execute("SELECT param FROM tableOfInterest ORDER BY param DESC FIRST %s;", (num_results,))
```

the way that looks bad but is safer then the previous

```
cur.execute("SELECT param FROM tableOfInterest ORDER BY param DESC FIRST %d;" % num_results)
```

Comment: What do you mean 'consider the datatype that row is in the database'?  the db is not mine; I can't change the format.  All I want to do is convert to the list described above.

Comment: @jml fair enough, just use float instead of str then. (edited)

Comment: Is this really the most elegant?  I was thinking there's something built in like tofloatlist(myweirdlist)...  maybe not

Comment: the most elegant is to just use the Decimals.  You get the sql query to order by and first five. there is no real way to avoid the rows being tuples, but you can use tuple expansion to make it look pretty.  (edited to give example of what I mean)

Comment: ok, how can i pass in the 5 as a variable to be concatenated in cur.execute()?  i've read that is a NONO.

Comment: @jml Concatenating the value into the sql in considered a bad because it opens you up to sql injection attacks.  However if the value you are concatenating is under your control and not some kind of input some would argue that is safe enough (for instance if it was %d and the type was an int).  The "right" way to do it is to use prepared statements and bind your variables into that. Unfortunately pyscopg doesn't handle these like they should. http://initd.org/psycopg/articles/2012/10/01/prepared-statements-psycopg/